# How to display api call response in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and i am working with nextjs, i tried to integrate "newsletter",
I created a component for this which is working fine but i am unable to display "success" or "error"
message in screen/WebsitePage,i am getting "success" message in console but "success/error" message
not showing
Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Subscribe = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            const emails = email;
            event.preventDefault();
            const res = await fetch('https://example.com/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email='+emails);
            const { error, message } = await res.json();
            if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    setError(error);
            } else {
                    console.log(message);
                    setSuccess(message);
            }
};
```

And i put following code just below my form close,But nothing is showing in my screen,How can i do this ?

```
{success 
    ? 
        <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-green-700"> 
        {success}
    </span> 
    : 
<span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-red-800">
{error} 
</span>
```

Comment: Please provide the full code in stackoverflow code snippet, or a live editor like codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have not taken the value from JSON properly. I have posted a demo code that is working exactly as you wanted.

Also, you have not used `===` operator for comparing string `true`. The status value of JSON is not in boolean it's a string.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState("");

  const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://mocki.io/v1/65583d53-9071-47af-b7d7-840e88763d08"
    );

    const data = await res.json();
    const error = data["status"];
    const message = data["msg"];

    if (error === "false") {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error);
    } else {
      console.log(message);
      setSuccess(message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <span>
        {" "}
        {error} {success}
      </span>
      <br />
      <button onClick={subscribeMe}>Press me </button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is a demo URL** https://yfv7c3.csb.app/

Comment: your code gave me solution,Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to trying to render an object,  try to JSON.stringify the data

Comment: as i said i am new in nexjs so can you update code so i can check and implement in my side

Comment: Hey, Ritika can you show us your JSON response so that I can try it on my laptop. Anyway, I have tried the dummy code and it's working fine for me. https://pastebin.com/Epwt1DeR

Comment: @NalinNishant: whenever i hit api i am getting following message as json response
{"status":true,"msg":"Email saved successfully"}

Comment: K give me 5 mins i am trying

Comment: @NalinNishant: i am also trying , according to me something wrong with following code
I just need to change correct if else condition ( means if we use same email id then giving us message "{"status":false,"msg":"Email already exist"} " so i just need to use if else condition according to response return, current code is


 if (error) {
                     const error='errror';
                     setError(error);
             } else {
      const message='subscribed successfully';
               console.log(message);
                     setSuccess(message);
             }

Comment: I solved it let me show you my code

Comment: @NalinNishant  sure i am waiting

Comment: @NalinNishant please show your code